# Weird Apache Crash (with Dump) zend_hash_find (), libphp5.so

Tags: apache-2.2, php, dump

To be honest I don't have experience working with Apache. I'm just putting the best of my intentions on solving this and don't know if I'm making it right. So any help will be greatly appreciated.

We have a php page wich is throwing the following message in the browser:

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

The logs from /var/log/httpd doesn't seem to help because It seems that the Apache is unable to write any information. So the exception or error is preventing the writing (maybe ocurring in some stage of the process that makes impossible to log?).

I've read about the procedure to make dumps of the apache, and here we have the content:

```
Reading symbols from /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/httpd'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
0  0x00007fb828fff712 in zend_hash_find () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1.x86_64
```

I've been looking in the PHP files and I haven't found any direct call to zend_hash_find (wich seems to be causing the error).

I've been looking at Google but found nothing related. Can somebody please help? Is there any step that I need to accomplish to know more?

Thanks a lot, as always!

Comment: And what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: ¡Thanks Michael!, PHP Version 5.3.3. Please, ask anything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't explain exactly the details of the issue, but the thing is that it was related with 'eAccelerator' (don't know if it's related to Zend, and more specifically zend_hash_find).

In order to fix it:

```
cd /etc/php.d/
mv eaccelerator.ini eaccelerator.ini_
```

Wich disables the component. Not sure, but I think that we're only loosing aspects connected to opcode cache.

Thanks to all readers!